# My regex captures only one date

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net

This is the regex i am using for capturing dates in format dd-MMM-yyyy

```
(\b\d{1,2}-(jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec)-(19|20)\d{2}\b)
```

I have tried grouping the entire regex but it captures only the first occurrence.

for example, in the string "BETWEEN 04-May-2015 AND 05-May-2015" it captures only 04-May-2015.

Here is the vb.net code:

```
Dim rx as regex = new regex("\b\d{1,2}-(jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec)-(19|20)\d{2}\b",(RegexOptions.Compiled Or RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
Dim m as match = rx.match(criteria)
if m.success then
    Console.Writeline(m.Groups(0).Captures.Count)
end if
```

Where am i going wrong? Any help would be great.

Comment: Please show your VB.NET code. http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cb%5cd%7b1%2c2%7d-(jan%7cfeb%7cmar%7capr%7cmay%7cjun%7cjul%7caug%7csep%7coct%7cnov%7cdec)-(19%7c20)%5cd%7b2%7d%5cb&i=BETWEEN+04-May-2015+AND+05-May-2015&o=i

Comment: You need to loop thru matches

Comment: You probably use the [`Match`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.match(v=vs.110).aspx) method instead of the [`Matches`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you expect multiple matches, you have to use [`Regex.Matches`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of [`Regex.Match`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(v=vs.110).aspx).

Given your input string and pattern, this code

```
Dim s = "BETWEEN 04-May-2015 AND 05-May-2015"
Dim results = Regex.Matches(s, "\b\d{1,2}-(jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec)-(19|20)\d{2}\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
Console.WriteLine(results.Count())
```

prints `2`, so your pattern itself works.

You could alter it to:

```
\b(\d{1,2})-(jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec)-((?:19|20)\d{2})\b
```

to capture the day, month, and year (if that is what you want).

Comment: The pattern can be improved to allow only `(\d|([0-2]\d)|(3[0-1]))` in the day part, but the answer is still correct.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Yes, but this still allows invalid dates, so IMHO there's no point in chaning the simple `\d{1,2}` to something else. If you only want to allow valid dates, you have to do the validation after the capturing.

Comment: @sloth Correct. it's just a suggestion, I know 31-feb-2015 will pass as a match.

Answer (score 2):

That is not a problem of your regex, it is because of the surrounding code that handles the regex. You don't show it, but you need to use the [Regex.Matches](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(v=vs.110).aspx) method, that returns a [MatchCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchcollection(v=vs.110).aspx) containing all matches.